# What is the best way to find a version of an androidx library, such as NavigationComponent, ViewModel, and so on?

Tags: android, package, version, androidx

About an hour trying to find the latest version of the navigation component library, but without success, so I wonder how I can quickly find the version of the package I need?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel), it says:

> **belongs to Maven artifact** `android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1`

So searching : `android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel` on the Google will show [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/android.arch.lifecycle/viewmodel/1.1.1) link which describes the versions and etc.

There is however a note section:

> Note: There is a new version for this artifact
>
> New Version 1.1.1

It was just an example which explains which version is the latest version for this library-dependency.

<sub>Note that this is also the same for other libaries-dependencies on jitpack or other repositories</sub>